# ordenar imagenes en base de datos

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql

Buenas, tengo una tabla productos y quiero que cada producto tenga una o varias imágenes. así que cree una tabla imágenes con una foreign key a productos.

algo asi:

```
create table producto(
  id_producto serial,
  nombre character varying(20),
  .... 
);

create table imagen(
  id_imagen serial,
  id_producto integer,
  nombre character varying(100),
  foreign key(id_producto) references producto(id_producto)
  ...
);
```

Hasta acá creo que voy bien, el problema es que quiero que al momento de crear un producto, este tenga una imagen principal (idealmente que se puedan ordenar), pero si pongo un campo como `principal boolean` en la tabla de imágenes y luego alguien agrega una imagen y la define como principal, tendré 2 imágenes principales, por lo que posiblemente se me dupliquen registros al hacer una query que llame solo a la principal.

No se si me explico bien, pero no veo como ser mas claro.

Lo único que se me ocurre es validar esto en el formulario, pero me gustaría saber si tengo alguna otra opción.

También me gustaría que las imágenes se pudieran ordenar. con un campo `posicion integer` o algo así.

Como funcionan paginas como mercadolibre en este sentido?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no he entendido mal lo que quieres hacer es que sólo una de las imágenes ligadas a un producto concreto esté marcada como principal.

Como tu mencionas eso se puede hacer previo a la inserción de cada imagen fuera de PostgreSQL, por ejemplo, cada vez que una imagen se marque como "principal" poniendo todas las existentes ligadas al producto desmarcadas con:

```
 UPDATE imagen SET principal = false WHERE id_producto = {id del producto implicado}
```

Pero si quieres hacerlo todo en PostgreSQL, una forma sería mediante trigger, tienes la documentación oficial en https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/triggers.html.

Sería similar, sólo tendrías que comprobar dentro del trigger si los valores que se están insertando/actualizando cambian "principal" y en caso de que lo hagan cambiar con un `UPDATE` similar al anterior los valores "principal" ligados al producto antes de hacer el nuevo update/insert.

Respecto a la ordenación, si tienes un campo integer podrías ordenar los registros por ese campo sin mayor problema, pero la lógica para mantener un "principal" sería mas complicada, imagino que sólo tendrías el campo entero y el que tenga valor 1 sería el "principal"; la lógica de inserción actualización en ese caso (también se podría hacer con trigger).

Comment: Me había olvidado de la existencia de los triggers. lo haré así creo que es mas practico ya que así puedo usar la misma base de datos para ir haciendo pruebas en varias aplicaciones.

Answer (score 2):

Para que un producto solo tenga una imagen principal, lo que se me ocurre es que en la tabla producto crees el campo imagenPrincipal y así aseguras que siempre tendrás solo una imagen principal, para lo de ordenar las imagenes, con un campo orden deberia ser suficiente.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes decir que tu producto tiene una imagen principal de la lista de imagenes.

```
create table producto(
  id_producto serial,
  nombre character varying(20),
  imagen_principal serial,
  constraint fk_imagen_producto foreign key (imagen_principal) references imagen(id_imagen)
);

create table imagen(
  id_imagen serial,
  id_producto integer,
  nombre character varying(100),
  foreign key(id_producto) references producto(id_producto)
);
```

al insertar un producto nuevo primero insertas la imagen que tendrá.

```
insert into imagen values (@idimagen,@idproducto,'nombre');
```

luego insertas el producto con la id de su imagen principal.

```
insert into producto values(@idproducto,'nombre',@idimagen);
```

Para agregar imagenes normales del producto, es lo mismo

```
insert into imagen values  (@idimagen,@idproducto,'nombre');
```

Para encontrar el producto con su imagen principal, lo puedes buscar por su id

```
select p.id_producto,p.nombre,i.nombre
from producto p inner join imagen i
on p.imagen_principal = i.id_imagen
where p.id_producto = @idProducto;
```

Para buscar todas sus imagenes incluyendo la principal

```
select id_imagen, nombre from imagen where id_producto = @idproducto;
```

Para buscar todas sus imagenes sin la principal

```
select i.id_imagen, i.nombre 
from imagen i inner join producto p
on i.id_producto = p.id_producto
where p.id_producto = @idproducto
and p.imagen_principal != i.id_imagen;
```

Comment: había pensado agregar el campo imagen a la tabla productos, pero no me gustaba tener que repetir el dato. No había pensado en usarlo como foreign key, pero igual no me termina de convencer, asi que terminare usando triggers para "validar" lo que venga. de todas formas, gracias

Comment: si sabes de los triggers entonces dudo que tengas problemas para resolverlo. Éxito!